# Нестрогое сравнение примитивов JS

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, если здесь true

```
"" == 0; // true
"0" == 0; // true
```

то почему здесь false ?

```
"" == "0"; // false
```

Comment: приведение типов ... когда строка сравнивается со строкой, приведения типов не происходит, так как тип у них один в итоге пустота сравнивается с нулем и это неверно

Comment: почитай про строгое и нестрогое сравнение в js, а так же про приведение типов

Comment: [Вот тут можно почитать про нестрогое сравнение](http://es5.javascript.ru/x11.html#x11.9.3)

Comment: Спасибо! Я думал, что они в любом случае к числу приводятся

Comment: потому что в первом случае, ты сравниваешь два разных типа и при нестрогом сравнении, они true...
а во втором случае, ты сравниваешь одного типа , а как известно пустая строка всегда false, а не пустая true... так что второй вариант идентичен  false == true...  естественно это false

Comment: Да, понял, спасибо!!